# problems with global namespace in namespaced section

Tags: php, namespaces

I have some problems with global name spaces in a name spaced section. That means, when i execute the function below, i get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'login\PDO' not found in /var/www/html/easyboard/scripts/php/functions.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/easyboard/users/login/login.php(42): login\checkUser('cripi') #1 /var/www/html/easyboard/index.php(8): require_once('/var/www/html/e...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/easyboard/scripts/php/functions.php on line 12
```

Code:

```
<?php
namespace login {
    #------------------------
    #check do user exists
    function checkUser($username)
    {
        $username = strtolower($username);
        global $pdo;
        global $login;
        $statement = "SELECT * FROM " . $login['tableName'] . " WHERE username = :username OR email = :email;";
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($statement);
        $statement->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindValue(':email', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if ($statement->execute()) {
            if ($statement->rowCount() >= 1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

//Cripi

Comment: `\PDO::PARAM_STR`

Comment: tanks, works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [global namespace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php). You have to write a `\` infront of global functions / classes.

*Answered by [Alex Blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110423/alex-blex) in the comments.*